# Can't subtract in a for loop in C/Objective-C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm going through the Big Nerd Ranch book on Objective-C, which takes you through some early C stuff. I've played with C before, and am pretty experienced in PHP.

Anyhow, I'm doing the challenges and this one is not working the way I think it should. It's pretty simple - start at 99, loop through and subtract three until you get to zero, and every time you get a number that is divisible by 5 print "Found one." Pretty straightforward. However, subtracting by three in the for loop is not working

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int i;
    for(i = 99; i > 0; i-3){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if(i % 5 == 0) {
            printf("Found one!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It creates and endless loop at 99, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You have to change `i-3` to `i -= 3` or `i = i-3`.

Comment: Any *good* compiler, with appropriate warning levels, would have told you about your error. e.g., use -Wall with gcc.

Answer (score 4):

`i-3` doesn't modify the variable `i`. Do something like -

```
 for( i=99; i>0; )
 {
      // ....
     i -= 3;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I see my logic break now.

Comment: Certainly correct fix, but that style seems pretty strange. Why not leave `i -= 3` inside the `for()` statement?

Comment: @sblom Some users already mentioned it. Just to provide a different solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `i-=3` instead of `i-3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int i;
    for(i = 99; i > 0; i-=3){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if(i % 5 == 0) {
            printf("Found one!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`i-3` does not change the value of `i`.

`i-=3` does.

Comment: Thanks guys. I see my logic break now.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop statement doesn't modify the value of `i`. Just doing `i - 3` doesn't *change* `i`, it just returns the value of `i - 3`.

Use: `for(i = 99; i > 0; i = i - 3)`

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, it should be `i=i-3`.

Answer (score 1):

You are just subtracting `3` from `i`, but you are not assigning it to `i`.
Use `i = i - 3` instead of just `i - 3`.

Change your for statement like this:

```
for(i = 99; i > 0; i = i - 3) {
  // Write your code here.
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but just for the sake of simplicity. i = i- 3;

Answer (score 0):

The Last Term in the For loop is the increment of decrement operation. While `i-3` is none. If you want the Value of i to get reduced by 3, then you should store that value in `i` itself.

To do that Following code should be written: `i = i-3` or shorthand `i-=3`.